# Angular paging generates wrong number of pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, paging

I am having a hard time getting the [Angular paging](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) to work correctly. The number of pages seems to be off. For example, for one of my searches, the number of returned results is 1005. Displaying 16 results per page, should have 63 pages total. Instead it generates 101. I appreciate any suggestions on why this is happening and how to resolve.

Thanks in advance!

```
<table class="table table-striped results">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th ng-repeat="x in json.headers">{{ x }}</th>
                        </tr>
                    <thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="x in filteredResults">
                            <td><a href="#">{{ x.name }}</a></td>
                            <td>{{ x.city }}</td>
                            <td>{{ x.state }}</td>
                            <td>{{ x.zip }}</td>
                            <td>{{ x.phone }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </ul>
                </table>
                <pagination         
                                    style="position:absolute; bottom:10px;"
                                    ng-show="json.results.length"
                                  ng-model="currentPage"
                                  total-items="json.results.length"
                                  max-size="maxSize"  
                                  boundary-links="true"
                                  next-text=">"
                                  last-text=">>"
                                  previous-text="<"
                                  first-text="<<">
                </pagination>
```

JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
        app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope, $http){

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.submit-search').click(function(){
                    $http.get('model/search_url.php', {
                        params: { searchBy: $scope.user.searchBy, search: $scope.user.search }
                    }).success(function (response){
                        $scope.json = response;
                        $scope.filteredResults = [];
                        $scope.currentPage = 1
                        $scope.numPerPage = 16
                        $scope.maxSize = 5;

                        $scope.$watch("currentPage + numPerPage", function() {
                            var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage);
                            var end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
                            $scope.filteredResults = $scope.json.results.slice(begin, end);
                        });
                    });
                });
        });
```

Comment: why you have used jquery in angular..that will messed up with digest cycle..please use `ng-click` instead

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can you please elaborate on why specifically using a jquery click event listener is a bad idea in this case? Also, is this related with why the paging is generating incorrectly?

Comment: look at this document https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/ or this http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `items-per-page`, in your case it should be 16, but since you don't provide it it set to the default of 10 items per page.

Comment: Perfect and makes sense! Working well now. Toda Raba!

Comment: In case some of us feel the Angular pagination directive provides too many options, look at this simple paging service. http://www.ozkary.com/2015/07/angularjs-data-grid-with-paging.html